# Show how to generate a token from a Rest API in R

Tags: r, rest

I got the Rest API:

https://data.xcmdata.org/ISGDE/api/token/v4/get

As well as my username and password. They gave me a sample

curl --location --request POST "https://data.xcmdata.org/ISGDE/api/token/v4/get" --header "Accept: application/json" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data "{"username" : "{userName}","password" : "{password}"}"

Comment: If you are just asking to convert that curl command to R, try a site like https://curlconverter.com/r/. So this will probably work `httr::contents(httr::POST(url = "https://data.xcmdata.org/ISGDE/api/token/v4/get", encode="json", body = list(username="{username}", password="{password}")))`. Hard to test without a username and password. There's no "standard" way to get a token so it can be different for every website.

Comment: pulled the brackets surrounding the username and password, and it was then good to go. Thank you.